# MSAL:3.0/Angular16: BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: Msal angular Error while calling on page load

Tags: angular, authentication, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I want to authenticate the user when ever user loads the webpage to achieve this i am using [MSAL Angular library (V3.0)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-angular-v3-samples) and handled redirects as per the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/redirects.md), But still i'm facing the below issue.

***BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.***

can any one let me know how to authenticate the user once page loaded successfully using MSAL
**app.module.ts**

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.msalConfig.auth.clientId,
      authority: environment.msalConfig.auth.authority,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/',
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage
    },
  })
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy{
  title = 'sso-poc';
  loginDisplay = false;
  private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(private msal:MsalService, private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msal.loginRedirect();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
   
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   
  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginDisplay = false;
  // private readonly _destroying$ = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(private msal: MsalService, private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {

      this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$.pipe(
        filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
      ).subscribe((result) => {   
        console.log("Login success")
        const payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;
        this.msal.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
      })
  
      this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$.pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None)
      ).subscribe((res) => {
          // UI activity
      })

  }

  checkLoginAccount() {
    console.log(this.msal.instance.getAllAccounts().length)
    return this.msal.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
  }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SsoPoc</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
</html>
```